# Couper la pomme en deux

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, alimentation

[« Couper la poire en deux »](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/couper-la-poire-en-deux.php) est une expression française qui signifie faire un compromis que l'on veut équitable. Elle est apparue au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle et son origine est incertaine.

J'ai été surpris de rencontrer la variante « couper la **pomme** en deux » qui semble avoir le même sens. Ainsi [cette demande de traduction en anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303155/english-idiom-cut-the-apple-in-half) (dans laquelle de nombreux commentateurs sont aussi surpris que moi de voir une pomme et non une poire). Si cela peut bien sûr être un jeu de mots, par exemple [parce que le compromis est lié à la société Apple](https://www.igen.fr/0-apple/webos-hp-veut-couper-la-pomme-en-deux-58652), j'ai bien trouvé quelques occurrences de « couper la pomme en deux » pour signifier « faire un compromis », au milieu de recettes de cuisine. L'usage est très minoritaire par rapport à la poire, mais diversifié :

- [dans *Marie-Claire* (21<sup>e</sup> s., France)](https://www.marieclaire.fr/,bronde-je-veux-une-couleur-bronde-pour-mes-cheveux,781578.asp)
- [dans le *Journal de Montréal* (2012, Québec)](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2012/09/18/avant-de-couper-la-pomme-en-deux-il-faut-la-distinguer-de-lorange)
- [dans un livre de Moncef Marzouki (1987, France)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Q5y5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22couper+la+pomme+en+deux%22&dq=%22couper+la+pomme+en+deux%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0h8r87tfhAhVHyYUKHQeeCEs4ChDoAQg3MAI)

Alors, est-ce une variante régionale minoritaire mais qui s'est diffusée ? Une variante ancienne moribonde ? Est-ce que certains utilisent d'autres fruits (et pas pour faire un jeu de mots) ?

Comment: Si "la pomme" voulait dire "le calva/apple brandy" comme "la poire" veut dire "pear brandy", peut-etre il y aurait un peu plus d'occurrences de "Couper la pomme en deux", au moins en Normandie!

Comment: Neither expression has a particularly catchy ring to it, unlike "au mois d'avril..." although poire is clearly the favorite, despite the prevalence of pommes as a preferred food. C'est une variante naturelle qui est tout a fait attendue par erreure en temps que variation de l'expression la plus populaire, mais qui n'amuse guere et s'oublie.

Answer (score 4):

D'après le [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la%20poire%20en%20deux%2Cla%20pomme%20en%20deux&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20poire%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20pomme%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0), il semble que « couper la pomme en deux » soit très peu utilisé.

« Couper la poire en deux » restera donc l'expression à privilégier.
[image: image ngram]

Comment: Et encore, une grande majorité de ces quelques pommes semblent être des occurences littérales.

Answer (score 1):

Le seul indice que j'ai trouvé d'une équivalence qui pourrait expliquer la substitution n'a rien à voir avec l'expression, ce serait dans le langage populaire comme substitut nominal au pronom personnel avec le possessif dans un contexte de suppléance qui n'est ni relié à l'économie linguistique ni au terme précédemment exprimé, et où *pomme* et *poire*, d'après le sens de « figure », sont tous les deux employés, entre autres (LBU §221 c 1) et incidemment le DHLF nous rappelle à « poire » que la métaphore du fruit pour « tête » est banale et indique « [...] pomme, fraise, citron etc. » :

> Ces tapins-là, c'est pas pour ma poire. (Aymé)
>  Ma tante est
>   drôlement mieux que vott' pomme. (Queneau)

Par ailleurs le texte du *Journal de Montréal* s'intitule « Avant de couper la pomme en deux, il faut la distinguer de l’orange », ce qui réfère clairement à l'adage de langue anglaise *apples and oranges* et donc il s'agit d'un jeu de mots banal ; on aurait probablement dû parler du *choux*, vu que la *carotte* se coupe difficilement en deux symétriquement, mais on a dû penser que les lecteurs comprendraient mieux la référence en contexte nord-américain. Si au moins la fermeté du fruit conditionnait le choix c'eût été excellent pour introduire une nuance de difficulté d'en arriver au compromis (la chair de la pomme étant plus ferme que celle la poire, il me semble) ; c'est pure spéculation et on ne pense pas que les choix s'appuient sur ce genre de réflexion.

---

En résumé à défaut de trouver plus d'informations (entre autres parce qu'au corpus écrit il y a possiblement un seuil à partir duquel un [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couper%20le%20*%20en%20deux%2Cle%20*%20en%20deux%2Cla%20*%20en%20deux%2Ccouper%20la%20*%20en%20deux%2Ccouper%20la%20fraise%20en%20deux%2Ccouper%20le%20citron%20en%20deux%2Ccouper%20la%20pomme%20en%20deux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccouper%20le%20%2A%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcouper%20le%20pays%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20le%20monde%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20le%20temps%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cle%20%2A%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20divise%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20diviser%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20partage%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20monde%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20pays%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20coupe%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20corps%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20s%C3%A9pare%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20partager%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20couper%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cla%20%2A%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bla%20division%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20divise%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20France%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20ville%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20diviser%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20partage%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20s%C3%A9paration%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nation%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20coupe%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccouper%20la%20%2A%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20poire%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20France%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20nation%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20ville%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20courbe%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20coalition%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ccouper%20le%20*%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcouper%20le%20pays%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20le%20monde%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20le%20temps%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cle%20*%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20divise%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20diviser%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20partage%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20monde%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20pays%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20coupe%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20corps%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20s%C3%A9pare%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20partager%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20couper%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cla%20*%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bla%20division%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20divise%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20France%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20ville%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20diviser%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20partage%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20s%C3%A9paration%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nation%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20coupe%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccouper%20la%20*%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20poire%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20France%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20nation%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20ville%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20courbe%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcouper%20la%20coalition%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0) montre des résultats et que le DHLF ne s'aventure même pas à traiter de l'expression) on est d'opinion qu'en langage populaire certains fruits sont plus ou moins interchangeables et que ça peut avoir un impact sur leur emploi dans ce genre d'expression, en particulier vu qu'on trouve que c'est surtout l'idée de couper, trancher symétriquement en deux et donner la chose qui porte l'expression davantage que l'objet lui-même considérant qu'au final il n'a rien à voir avec le sens de *faire un compromis*.

Comment: Le ngram fourni [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34828/17649) ne reflète pas une notion de « plus ou moins» ; on constate une légère divergence que l'on peut imputer au manque d'éducation de certains auteurs, à leur  maque de soin  en vertu de leur devoir de s'assurer des termes qu'ils emploient et au peu de soucis qu'ils ont de préserver une langue efficace. « Couper la poire en deux » est une expression bien établie et permettre toute une variété à sa place n'apporte rien. Pour citer un chroniqueur : « La variété c'est l'épice de la mort.».